# Data isn't saved in nested service call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Please assume following code:

```
@RestController
class C {

  @Autowired
  Service1 service1;

  @PostMapping
  Result someChanges(Data data) {
    return service1.update(data);
  }
}

class Service1 {

  @Autowired
  Service2 service2;

  @Aautowired
  Service1Repo s1repo;

  @Transactional
  Result update(Data data){
    service2.doBussinesLogic();
    s1repo.save(data);
  }

}

class Service2 {

  @Autowired
  Service2Repo s2Repo;

  void doBussinesLogic(){
    List users = getUsers();
    //alter users
    s2Repo.saveAll(users);
  }
}
```

When I hit someChanges endpoint, I get strange results. I expect that both service calls will persist data into database, but for some unknown for me reason I got saved only s1repo.save(data). As for s2Repo.saveAll(users) users aren't updated for some reason. I think due to transaction rollback, but why is s1repo.save(data) saved then? Why do I have so strange behaviour? What cases I should check?
I want both repo calls persisted in database, but got persisted only repo1 call. I use Spring Boot, Spring Data, Hibernate.

Comment: Is there any relationship between `data` and `users`? Can you add the corresponding entity classes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate defines and supports the Transient, Persistent, Detached object states.

doBussinesLogic method is not transactional in your case.

getUsers() is another method that is fetching records from the database.
So only reason looking here, Entities (users list) is in detached mode inside the doBussinesLogic method.

getUsers method has completed its transaction. then you are trying to change and update in user list inside of the doBussinesLogic method which has been detached.

solution:- make these methods trasactional properly.